# Distinguishing bad alternator diode from short

Tags: troubleshooting, alternator, diagnostics

Is there a good way without disassembly to distinguish between an alternator with a bad diode and a high resistance short in the alternator (between the output and housing) caused by moisture/corrosion/etc.? The problem I'm experiencing, battery drain while car is off, seems like it could equally be explained by either (among other things, but see below for why I think there's a problem at the alternator).

I'm measuring 940 ohms reverse across the alternator (+ to alternator output cable disconnected from fuse box, - to chassis ground) but I suspect this could be explained by either. Alternator gives seemingly good output when running (16V disconnected from fusebox, around 14V connected) as best I can tell, but that's just with a basic multimeter; I don't have a scope to look for AC/ripple.

I'm also measuring 500 ohms in the forward direction across the alternator (same methodology but probes flipped) which seems odd. Is that possibly a normal consequence of how the multimeter sees voltage drop from the diodes, or sign of something wrong?

Comment: Don’t run an alternator that is not connected to a battery.

Comment: Test each diode individually, so you will need to disconnect each one.

Comment: *without disassembly*

Comment: Re: "not connected to battery", I think you're thinking about the case where the alternator is connected to the car's electrical system and there's no battery connected, which indeed could damage all sorts of things. If the alternator is disconnected entirely (including the voltage regulator), there are no moving magnetic fields present because an alternator has no permanent magnets. If you leave the regulator connected, there may be ways in which it could be damaging to the alternator, but it's unlikely; it's running at no load.

Comment: Residual magnetism is a thing.

Comment: Your other post explained a faulty alternator; "I have an alternator that likely bad diodes - erratic output, drains the battery when off, etc. Automated in-vehicle test at an auto parts shop also reported bad diode as the problem." Your own testing revealed a faulty diode (at least one of six). Your refusal to accept a faulty alternator is obvious to many whether having a degree or not. Review youtube videos unless you already have, related to testing without disassembling one but unable understand your results.

Comment: What is the model number of the alternator?

Comment: @FDryer: I don't refuse to believe; I just prefer to do sufficient diagnostics to be confident I know what's wrong before putting a lot of effort and money into something that might not solve the problem.

Comment: @HandyHowie: I'm pretty sure any externally visible marking deteriorated a long time ago but I'll chevk.